# WolframAlpha and the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos(\pi k)}{\csc(\pi k)}$

Tags: trigonometric-series, wolfram-alpha

**Question**: WolframAlpha gives the following expression $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos(\pi k)}{\csc(\pi k)}=\phi(n);$$
where $\phi()$ is the Euler totient function. You can check for yourself [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+cos%28pi*k%29%2Fcsc%28pi*k%29+from+k%3D1+to+n). Is this incorrect ?

---

Surely $\frac{\cos(\pi k)}{\csc(\pi x)}=0$ for every natural number $k,$ and so the sum should always equal zero. Am I misinterpreting the output from WolframAlpha or did I type it in wrong ? I know that $\frac{\cos(\pi k)}{\csc(\pi x)}=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\pi k),$ whose partial sum WolframAlpha correctly shows: [check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F2sin%282*pi*k%29+from+k%3D1+to+n).

Comment: Looks like a bug as Mathematica returns Sum[Cos[Pi k]/Csc[Pi k], {k, 1, n}] = 0

Comment: I have a version of Mathematica that returns `EulerPhi[n]`, version 12.0.0.0 on macOS

Comment: Interesting! I am Windows 10, x86, running version 12.1.1.0.  Maybe we could post this on the Mathermatica Stack Exchange.

Comment: Should I cross-post ? Is that allowed ?

Comment: The MMA group would want MMA only and MMA code in the post - not WA.